# qt desktop-приложение под все экраны

Tags: qt

Писал прогу и совсем забыл что не у всех экраны с таким большим разрешением. При открытии на небольшом разрешении экрана половину проги не видно. Как это решается на примере qt хотя бы примерно. основная работа проги в mainwindow (maximized) все виджеты расположены очень плотно. Может сделать два разных окна mainwindow и проверку на размер монитора? Как правильно?

Comment: Два может оказаться мало. Создаете Grid Layout, что бы удобно менять размер окна туда забрасываете свои виджеты. Считываете текущий размер экрана и делаете на 3/4-х экрана. Единственное, что нужно будет подогнать растягивание виджетов под разные экраны что бы было поменьше спейсов.

Comment: спасибо. Есть над чем подумать!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QRect screenRect(QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry());
```

И относительно актуального размера экрана корректировать размер интерфейса.

Например, [вот так это делают](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/d460897f84bad314302df1198b3dbcf3f11bf653/Telegram/SourceFiles/platform/linux/main_window_linux.cpp#L438) в Telegram Desktop:

```
void MainWindow::psInitSize() {
    setMinimumWidth(st::wndMinWidth);
    setMinimumHeight(st::wndMinHeight);

    TWindowPos pos(cWindowPos());
    QRect avail(QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()); // <--------<<<
    bool maximized = false;
    QRect geom( avail.x() + (avail.width() - st::wndDefWidth) / 2,
                avail.y() + (avail.height() - st::wndDefHeight) / 2,
                st::wndDefWidth,
                st::wndDefHeight);

    if (pos.w && pos.h) {
        QList<QScreen*> screens = Application::screens();
        for (auto i = screens.cbegin(), e = screens.cend(); i != e; ++i) {
            QByteArray name = (*i)->name().toUtf8();
            if (pos.moncrc == hashCrc32(name.constData(), name.size())) {
                QRect screen((*i)->geometry());
                int32 w = screen.width(), h = screen.height();
                if (w >= st::wndMinWidth && h >= st::wndMinHeight) {
                    if (pos.w > w) pos.w = w;
                    if (pos.h > h) pos.h = h;

                    pos.x += screen.x();
                    pos.y += screen.y();

                    if (pos.x < screen.x() + screen.width() - 10 
                        && pos.y < screen.y() + screen.height() - 10)
                    {
                        geom = QRect(pos.x, pos.y, pos.w, pos.h);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if (pos.y < 0) pos.y = 0;
        maximized = pos.maximized;
    }
    setGeometry(geom);
}
```